# Passing a parameter by url with window.open

Tags: javascript, asp.net, parameter-passing

I'd like to pass a paramater by url:

i'm doing it this way:

```
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="lnkModifier" runat="server" ImageUrl="../Logos/edit.png" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("idAgir") %>'
                            CommandName="Select" ToolTip="Modifier" OnClick="lnkModifier_Click" OnClientClick="Navigate(<%# Eval("idAgir") %>);return false;" />



<script type="text/javascript">

    function Navigate(id) {

        window.open("test1.aspx?id=" + id, "fenetre_popup", "toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,scrollbars=0,width=800,height=270");
        return false;
    } 

</script>
```

This is not working so far , a problem over there i guess : `OnClientClick="Navigate(<%# Eval("idAgir") %>);return false;"`

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
OnClientClick='<%# Eval("idAgir","Navigate({0})") %>'
```

Comment: Still have a problem with this :

                            <asp:ImageButton ID="lnkModifier" runat="server" ImageUrl="../Logos/edit.png" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("idAgir") %>'
                                CommandName="Select" ToolTip="Modifier" OnClick="lnkModifier_Click" OnClientClick="<%# Eval("idAgir","Navigate({0})") %>;return false;"/>

Comment: Try that with single quotes: OnClientClick='<%# Eval("idAgir","Navigate({0})") %>;return false;'/>